How can I run a docker image created in a linux environment on windows?
I have pulled a docker image of a simple expressjs server, exposing port 3000 on a docker desktop on windows. When i try running any command starting with docker in the integrated terminal, I am told that docker does not exist. How can I solve this?
I would like to map port 3000 exposed by the docker container to my host environment's port 80.
The command that I tried to input but could not be accepted is:
docker run -p 8080:3000 xpserver

Did you integrate Docker with WSL?

Thanks a lot for this. I have just installed and configured WSL, and now I have been able to run it. Really appreciate your assistance.

The easiest way to work with docker in my exp, it is using the docker desktop app for windows; you can even configure it and integrate it to work with WSL2. After that, it works like a charm and all ports are available in either the windows machine or the wsl instance.
Here it is the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/

After integration of the app with WSL it worked. Thanks.
